# using XCTAssertEqual with NSString as error message argument

Tags: objective-c, xcode, xcode5

This is an example of how I would use XCTAssertEqual

```
XCTAssertEqual(valueA, valueB, @"message");
```

However, when I try the following

```
NSString *message = @"message";
XCTAssertEqual(valueA, valueB, message);
```

I get a compiler error, namely,

```
Expected ')'
```

It seems like I am simply passing an NSString either way. When i dig into the definition I find

```
#define XCTAssertEqual(a1, a2, format...) _XCTPrimitiveAssertEqual(a1, a2, ## format)
```

Which I cannot make heads or tails of.  Why am I unable to pass an `NSString*` as the `format...` argument into XCTAssertEquals, when it accepts NSString literals like `@"message"`?

Note: This appears to be the case for all the assertions.

Answer (score 14):

Try this:

```
XCTAssertEqual(valueA, valueB, @"%@", message);
```